# How to remove duplicate wildfly cache-control properties

Tags: spring, jsf, caching, wildfly, myfaces

I have an application with spring 4.0.3, primefaces 5.3, myfaces 2.2.9 and wildfly-9.0.2.Final and I followed https://gist.github.com/remibantos/5e86829e1ba6ad64eea1 to configure cache static resources but when I see in Chrome the Cache-Control is:

```
max-age=600, public, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

and the static resources are not cached.

Please anybody can help me?

Comment: So this does not occur when you don't use PrimeFaces?

Comment: I don't know because we have used primefaces all the time

Comment: Hello, I have the same problem with a project with almost same technologies.

The browser shows me `no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate` although JSF is supposed to handle this headers, no resource is cached. Is there any way to override this cache headers with wildfly?

Comment: You are using myfaces to and you did not use that tag...

Comment: So it works if you use the default Mojarra jsf impl? Or use a page that does not use spring? Did you test? Since that is what the tags you use indicate. Tags are **not** for what you use, but where the problem is. Excluding things is part of debugging. And as you can see in the gist, it only works for certain 'extensions'... Do they match? Please investigate more yourself. Easier to do for you than for us